# I'm trying to implement a view stack in swiftui and my @State objects are being reset for reasons that are unclear to me

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to swiftui and doing an experiment with pushing and popping views with a stack. When I pop a view off the stack, the @State variable of the prior view has been reset and I don't understand why.

This demo code was tested on macos.

```
import SwiftUI

typealias Push = (AnyView) -> ()
typealias Pop = () -> ()

struct PushKey: EnvironmentKey {
    
    static let defaultValue: Push = { _ in }
    
}

struct PopKey: EnvironmentKey {
    
    static let defaultValue: Pop = {() in }
    
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    
    var push: Push {
        get { self[PushKey.self] }
        set { self[PushKey.self] = newValue }
    }
    
    var pop: Pop {
        get { self[PopKey.self] }
        set { self[PopKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var stack: [AnyView]

    var body: some View {
        currentView()
            .environment(\.push, push)
            .environment(\.pop, pop)
            .frame(width: 600.0, height: 400.0)
    }
    
    public init() {
        _stack = State(initialValue: [AnyView(AAA())])
    }
    
    private func currentView() -> AnyView {
        if stack.count == 0 {
            return AnyView(Text("stack empty"))
        }
        return stack.last!
    }
    
    public func push(_ content: AnyView) {
        stack.append(content)
    }
    
    public func pop() {
        stack.removeLast()
    }
}

struct AAA : View {
    @State private var data = "default text"
    @Environment(\.push) var push

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $data)
            Button("Push") {
                self.push(AnyView(BBB()))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BBB : View {
    @Environment(\.pop) var pop

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Pop") {
                self.pop()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I type some text into the editor then hit Push, then Pop out of that view, I was expecting the text editor to maintain my changes but it reverts to the default text.

What am I missing?

Edit:

I guess this is really a question of how are NavigationView and NavigationLink implemented.  This simple code does the what I'm trying to do:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    @State var text = "default text"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
            NavigationLink(destination: MyView()) {
                Text("Push")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}
```

run that on iOS so you get a nav stack. edit the text, then push. Edit again if you want, then go back and see state is retained.

My code is trying to do the same thing in principle.

Comment: Views should don't be stored in an `@State` you need an `@ViewBuilder` to pass as a parameter. I suggest you start with the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui), watch the [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) video and maybe even review the rest of the basics WWDC videos. `AnyView` is discouraged by Apple.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. Rather than trying to store the views themselves in an array, you should consider storing the states that represent the views in the array and then render based on those.

Comment: But the purpose of the exercise is push an arbitrary view onto the stack, such that the containing view has no concept of what view's will be presented. What good would it do to stare state in the stack if the containing view has no idea what kind of view will be rendered?

Comment: @loremipsum I am aware of the AnyView situation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll share this attempt maybe it will help you create your version of this.

This all started with an attempt to create something like `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` but being able to back track to a random `View` in the stack

I have a protocol where an object returns a `View`. Usually it is an `enum`. The `view()` references a `View` with a `switch` that provides the correct child `View`. The `ContentView`/`MainView` works almost like a storyboard and just presents whatever is designated in the `current` or `path` variables.

```
//To make the View options generic
protocol ViewOptionsProtocol: Equatable {
    associatedtype V = View
    @ViewBuilder func view() -> V
}
```

This is the basic navigation router that keep track of the main view and the `NavigationLink`/`path`. Which looks similar to what you want to do.

```
//A generic Navigation Router
class ViewNavigationRouter<T: ViewOptionsProtocol>: ObservableObject{
    
    //MARK: Variables
    var home: T
    //Keep track of your current screen
    @Published private (set) var current: T
    //Keep track of the path
    @Published private (set) var path: [T] = []
    //MARK: init
    init(home: T, current: T){
        self.home = home
        self.current = current
    }
    //MARK: Functions
    //Control how you get to the screen
    ///Navigates to the nextScreen adding to the path/cookie crumb
    func push(nextScreen: T){
        //This is a basic setup just going forward
        path.append(nextScreen)
    }
    ///Goes back one step in the path/cookie crumb
    func pop(){
        //Use the stored path to go back
        _ = path.popLast()
    }
    ///clears the path/cookie crumb and goes to the home screen
    func goHome(){
        path.removeAll()
        current = home
    }
    ///Clears the path/cookie crumb array
    ///sets the current View to the desired screen
    func show(nextScreen: T){
        goHome()
        current = nextScreen
    }
    ///Searches in the path/cookie crumb for the desired View in the latest position
    ///Removes the later Views
    ///sets the nextScreen
    func dismissTo(nextScreen: T){
        while !path.isEmpty && path.last != nextScreen{
            pop()
        }
        if path.isEmpty{
            show(nextScreen: nextScreen)
        }
    }
    
}
```

It isn't an `@Environment` but it can easily be an `@EnvrionmentObject` and all the views have to be in the `enum` so the views are not completely unknown but it is the only way I have been able to circumvent `AnyView` and keep views in an `@ViewBuilder`.

I use something like this as the main portion in the main view `body`

```
router.path.last?.view() ?? router.current.view()
```

Here is a simple implementation of your sample

```
import SwiftUI

class MyViewModel:  ViewNavigationRouter<MyViewModel.ViewOptions> {
    //In some view router concepts the data that is /preserved/shared among the views is preserved in the router itself.
    @Published var preservedData: String = "preserved"
    init(){
        super.init(home: .aaa ,current: .aaa)
    }
    
    enum ViewOptions: String, ViewOptionsProtocol, CaseIterable{
        case aaa
        case bbb
        
        @ViewBuilder func view() -> some View{
            ViewOptionsView(option: self)
        }
    }
    
    struct ViewOptionsView: View{
        let option: ViewOptions
        var body: some View{
            switch option {
            case .aaa:
                AAA()
            case .bbb:
                BBB()
            }
            
        }
    }
}
struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var router: MyViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView {
                router.path.last?.view() ?? router.current.view()
            }
            .toolbar(content: {
                //Custom back button
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading, content: {
                    if !router.path.isEmpty {
                        Button(action: {
                            router.pop()
                        }, label: {
                            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 2, content: {
                                Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                                if router.path.count >= 2{
                                    Text(router.path[router.path.count - 2].rawValue)
                                }else{
                                    Text(router.current.rawValue)
                                }
                            })
                            
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
            .navigationTitle(router.path.last?.rawValue ?? router.current.rawValue)
        }.environmentObject(router)
    }
}


struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}

struct AAA : View {
    //This will reset because the view is cosmetic. the data needs to be preserved somehow via either persistence or in the router for sharing with other views.
    @State private var data = "default text"
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: MyViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $data)
            TextEditor(text: $vm.preservedData)
            Button("Push") {
                vm.push(nextScreen: .bbb)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BBB : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: MyViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Pop") {
                vm.pop()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum. I've exploring a generics solution today and I'll give your code a whirl tonight.