# SwiftUI Iterate through all possible Views

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

In Swift, you have views, views, and more views. and i'm trying to make a dynamic list of views that is varied by the files in a group.

- Im aware that the groups are not saved on app creation
- I cant use Init() in a view because that implies that the view was activated by an outside source (NavigationView for example)
- Having a static variable is saved on app startup so i could probably do something like that.

But Essentially i'm trying to be lazy/clever and do something that you can do in java, like iterate through every class in a package and instantiate those objects as you need. I want a NavigationView that's Dynamic, like i can add an Annotation (attribute in this case, but probably not helpful for my problem, just an ides) to my Views, and have a for loop iterate through an array that contains all my possible view objects and give me a navigationView for that.

I COULD just make a Statically configured list of Views ie [v1(), v2(), v3(), v4()...] and just do a ForEach through that and work that way, i just don't want to have to configure that in the main file when i cold probably do it dynamically (if possible) and just write a new class, and at the top put like an annotation and have it auto add to an Array that i'm managing dynamically.

I know you can iterate through files, but files on compile are not in the same structure (no folders etc...) but even if i could i don't know how to do that, and add all vies to a large Set of views for a navigation pane. Like a ForEach of [arr of views] each becoming a navigation link. and i can get the Name of the View by doing View.name or whatever

TLDR:
I want to have my Views Automatically Add themselves to a Static data list (Array of Views probably) and be able to have a navigationView Dynamically just add it to the clickable NavViews and replace this:
[image: Image of what i'm trying to replace]

With something that is just a loop of all my possible views that i've declared somehow.

Is this possible? if so how would i go about doing something like this
also, i know its probably not the best idea, but for the sake of learning id like to understand how to do this, then maybe a better way of going about what i want so i don't have a centralized place, and i can make it dynamic

Comment: The only version I have tried of this is have a `View` with a `switch` attached to an `enum`. The `View` serves as a `Set` of sorts and the `case` is the identifier. Then you can use `YourEnum.allCases` to iterate and use `case.view()` to get the `View`. Arrays are a bad idea because they force `AnyView` so they conform to the same type and Apple discourages that practice.

Comment: I would need to instance all of these views to get into the Enum wouldn't i?
I need to register all Views in a NavigationView (Not a single View will be ignored) and i need that to be the NavigationView

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982225/im-trying-to-implement-a-view-stack-in-swiftui-and-my-state-objects-are-being/69996884#69996884) is a mini version so you can see the implementation

Comment: I might not be explaining myself the best, Lets assume that i have 5 views that i want to have in a navigation link, is there a way i can add them to an array as View objects, and have like a variable inside them thats a name or whatever and have that array be iterated somewhere adding them to a navigation link

Comment: You can by making them conform to `AnyView` but [Apple discourages that practice](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022)